# Como puedo hacer que me saque el promedio de una fila?c++

Tags: c++, array

Ocupo de su ayuda, estoy haciendo un programa sobre cinco agencias las cuales ingresan 12 datos cada una; estos doce datos corresponden a los meses.
Me pide el problema que saque el promedio de ventas del mes de diciembre
Se supone que tiene que tomar todos los datos de diciembre (columna 12) y sacar el promedio, he estado intentando de otras formas pero no me da resultado, agradeceria mucho su ayuda

```
¿Cuál fue el total de ventas en el año de la agencia Lomas?
¿Cuál fue el promedio de ventas en el mes de diciembre?
¿Qué agencia tuvo mayores ventas en el mes de mayo?
¿En qué mes se registraron las menores ventas del año, considerando todas las agencias?
Lomas
Vallejo
Perisur
del Valle
Oriente

*/
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class autos{
    public:
        void anadir(float agencias [][12]){
            for(int fila=1;fila<6;fila++){
                for(int col=1;col<=12;col++){
                    cout<<"Ingresa un numero:"<<fila<<"  "<<col<<"  ";cin>>agencias[12][5];
                }
            }
        }
        
        void ventasPromedioDiciembre(float agencias[][12]){
            int fila=6; float suma, promedio;
                for(int col=0; col<=12; col++){
                suma=suma+agencias[fila][col];
  }
            promedio=suma/5;    
            cout<<"El promedio de ventas del mes de Diciembre es"<<promedio<<endl;
}
    

void ventasAnualesLomas(float agencias[][12]){
  int col=0, suma;
  for(int fila=0; fila<=11; fila++){
    suma=suma+agencias[fila][col];
  } 
  cout<<"la venta Anual de la sucursal Lomas es  "<<suma<<endl;
} 

};

int main(){
    
        float agencias [5][12]={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
    autos autoss;
    autoss.anadir(agencias);
    autoss.ventasPromedioDiciembre(agencias);
    autoss.ventasAnualesLomas(agencias);

}
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu arreglo es una matriz de 5 agencias con la información de los 12 meses de cada una. Agreguemos un paso intermedio para que sea más claro.

Este código:

```
struct Agencia {
    float meses[12] = {};
};

Agencia agencias[5];
```

Es equivalente a este:

```
float agencias [5][12]={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
```

---

Cuando cargas los datos, esta línea está mal. Recurda que las posiciones comienzan por 0. No tienes 13 agencias con 6 meses. No existe esa posición en el arreglo. Las posiciones están al revés.

```
cin >> agencias[12][5];
```

Nota también que forma parte de un for y las posiciones son constantes. Intuyo que lo que quieres es que se llene todo el arreglo así que reemplazaremos `12` y `5` por las variables de iteración.

Cambiemos la nomenclatura también para hacerlo más claro. La función queda así:

```
void anadir(Agencia agencias[], int cantidad){
    for (int nAgencia = 0; nAgencia < cantidad; nAgencia++){
        for (int nMes = 0; nMes < 12; nMes++){
            cout << "Ingresa un numero:" << (nAgencia + 1) << "  " << nMes << "\n";
            cin >> agencias[nAgencia].meses[nMes];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Ahora, para calcular el promedio hay 2 problemas.

- La variable `suma` contiene un valor indeterminado. Necesitas inicializarla (a 0 en este caso).
- `fila` es constante cuando necesitas calcular el promedio de todas las agencias.
- Tienes 12 meses pero sumas hasta el 13º (posición 12).

Arreglando eso el código queda así:

```
void ventasPromedioDiciembre(Agencia agencias[], int cantidad){
    float suma = 0, promedio;
    for (int nAgencia = 0; nAgencia < cantidad; nAgencia++)
        suma += agencias[nAgencia].meses[11];
    
    promedio = suma / cantidad;
    cout << "El promedio de ventas del mes de Diciembre es" << promedio << endl;
}
```

---

A modo de comentario, una clase idealmente es autocontenida. No necesita depender de variables del exterior.

En tu código dependes de la variable `agencias` que se encuentra en la función `main`.

Para usar la clase de esa manera, es mejor que uses funciones normales y no una clase. Puedes probar el código [aquí](https://tio.run/##zVJNT4QwFLz3V0zWCxtWLej6BbuJiR48mHhfOdRSSRMohMJeNvz2teVTYjYx8SKB8vrezLRvWl4U5wnnx@OZVDytY4FQ5roqBcu2hNRaqgSKZUIXjAvoKg4IMeWaV3hMhOKS4UBgns80ZxUMUOid50fY4NAExLxkn8sYTLFYls7AYd1f76IVpKrAmapkzOJlL5aXcGxeDYQNaDDNwpEwJV23J88FXoXuyTYK4fldOIPbh@d1hTDE4kUlpdAMtYKqM1HmDwubd8bVXXjLFgm0lU7ZzN/VIphrSoXtdup2kIguOqMsM5ooDenGpjdtL1TF9FuZZyKW@ZPkUmQfpfi1i@2R6Dpr7Vuh6IWCv3g8brbVdTenm/O8vrV2GBY3q7TMy0mezOx/TiesuY6dByZK7eWymdEHCN36P8JNLFScBtZA21nGpHJ6M354tv6@u/56DsUV1suueuoI5sjmePQofIorimuKNcUNxS3FHcU9hUfNZ@qeT8l/hn0B).

Un ejemplo de como usar bien una clase:

```
class Autos {
public:
    Agencia agencias[5] = {};

    void anadir(){
        ...
    }
    
    void ventasPromedioDiciembre(){
        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

Nota que las funciones de la clase no toman parámetros, las `agencias` simplemente forman parte de la clase.